# How to avoid SameSite 2minute window for "Lax+POST" temporary intervention?

Tags: google-chrome, samesite

Is there a chrome flag to avoid 2-minute window for "Lax+POST" temporary intervention?  This way we can test impact on our sites when this behavior will  be removed in the future.

Reference from https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site
Note that the 2-minute window for "Lax+POST" is a temporary intervention and will be removed at some point in the future (some time after the Stable launch of Chrome 80), at which point cookies involved in these flows will require `SameSite=None` and `Secure` even if under 2 minutes old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 2019/11/21 [this update](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site#20191121) has been added:

> Lax+POST temporary mitigation can be disabled for testing purposes using the new flag `--enable-features=SameSiteDefaultChecksMethodRigorously`

However, if you are addressing this by adding the appropriate `SameSite` flag to your cookies then be aware that the Lax+POST mitigation **does not** apply to cookies that have a `SameSite` attribute set. Explicitly setting the `SameSite` attribute will ensure consistent behaviour across different versions and flags.